A method to traverse in both permutation and combination
if i have an array for example array = [1,2,3,4] and i should have output like
1
2
3
4
1,2
1,3
1,4
2,3
2,4
3,4
1,2,3
1,2,4
1,3,4
2,3,4
1,2,3,4

i did try various methods but i doesn,t yield expected output
for(int i = 0;i<n-1;i++){
   for(int j = i+1;j<n;j++){
       System.out.println(array[i]+","+array[j]);
   }
}

the above method only print two values only for example
1,2
1,3
1,4
2,3
2,4
3,4

another method is
for(int i = 0;i<n-1;i++){
   for(int j = 0;j<i+1;j++){
       System.out.print(array[j]);
   }
   System.out.println();
}

it gives output like:
1
1,2
1,2,3
1,2,3,4

i also tried various method but i need a combination of all the method in a single method

Your last snippet doesn't print commas... how did you get the commas in the output?

What you are looking for what is called the powerset of the input array:
for (long i = (1 << array.length) - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    List<Integer> selected = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
        if (((i >> j) & 1) == 1) {
            selected.add(array[j]);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(selected.toString());
}

This prints all the possible subsequences (subsets) of the input array. The order is not the same as you have presented it. If that is important, then there are of course alternatives.
